# javascript query string > window.location.search.substring > using # instead of ? to start query string

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, query-string, window.location, url-parameters

I'm trying to **extract hash substring values from window.location** and write them into HTML for the user to see, with an URL syntax that disallows use of `?` as query string delimiter.

Ok, so I have this great code example, thanks to @Gabe:

```
<html>

<input type="button" id="test" value="Test" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {

        window.location = (window.location);
        GetURLParameter('source');  

    });

});

function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    console.log(sPageURL);

    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {

            alert(sParameterName[1]);

            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

I made one modifcatin to his example, so we're using the actual window location from the client ::

```
window.location = (window.location);
```

When I hit the "test" submit button on a page containing the above code (the URL is formed like this):

http://example.com/pagename.html#source=FOO&medium=BAR&campaign=FRED

(notice no `?` as query string delimiter, just `#`)

... then I get a successful alert, that shows the source "FOO" from the URL. Awesome.

**But how to I get the other two SParamaterNames**, and then **how do I write them into the page as HTML** rather than return an alert.

I know this is a basic question for you guys. I'm here because I have been trying to solve this problem for days now, looking at many diff solutions. Any help is greatly appreciated!! thank you very much to all you wizards.

Answer (score 3):

Just get the `hash` value instead of the `search` value from the `location` `object`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsKcr/) is a working example.

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
   var sPageURL = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
   for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
   {
     var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
     if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
     {
        return sParameterName[1];
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, did not work for me. I updated my code example after your answer.

Comment: I don't see that you made an attempt in your update to use the hash. Clearly it works with my jsfiddle example.

Comment: thanks Gabe ... will look at your fiddle more carefully. I tried implementing your solution on my server, but did not work. Will try again.

Comment: OK @gabe, modified your fiddle example slightly. Any help here with my clarified question would make you a god in my eyes. :)

Comment: I am kind of late to the party, but how do you get the second variable out of the query string in the fiddle example? I can only seem to get the first one